# Find a suitable Möbius transformation that maps $X=\{z|\ |z|<1, |z-q/2|<q/2\}$ onto the annulus $Y=\{z|\ p<|z|<1\}$ for some $p,q\in(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $p,q\in(0,1)$ define $X=\{z\in\Bbb{C}||z|<1, |z-q/2|<q/2\}$ and $Y=\{z\in\Bbb{C}|\ p<|z|<1\}$. We have to construct a mobious transformation that maps $X$ onto $Y$.
[image: Region X and Y]

There is a hint suggests $\displaystyle{T(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}}$ for suitable $a\in\Bbb{C}$ may do the job. But I don't know how did they get this transformation and what it does.
Can anyone help with the transformation? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What do you know about the mapping behaviour of $T(z)$ when $\lvert a\rvert < 1$?

Comment: I checked that this $T$ maps the unit disc onto itself.

Comment: A good start. What more? Zeros, invariant lines/circles?

Comment: I know a mobious transformation maps lines/circles to lines/circles.

Comment: Yes, but of particular interest are always lines/circles that are mapped to themselves, like fixed points are of particular interest. Do you know a line/circle mapped to itself by $T$?

Comment: Here if $a$ is real, then $f(1)=1$ and $f$ maps the unit circle to a circle passing through $f(1)=1$. So only such circle possible is unit circle. So $f$ maps the unit circle onto itself.

Comment: Good. For $\lvert a\rvert < 1$, $T$ is an automrphism of the unit disc, thus the unit circle is always invariant. When $a$ is real, then also the real line (more precisely, $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$) is mapped to itself. Generally, for $a \neq 0$, the line $a\cdot \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$. But looking at the picture strongly suggests using a real $a$. You want the circle $\lvert z - q/2\rvert = q/2$ mapped to the circle $\lvert z\rvert = p$. What would be good targets for the points $0$ and $q$ to be mapped to?

Comment: Target of 0 and $q$ could be$-p$ and $p$ respectively.

Comment: Yup. Now, we don't know the value of $p$ yet, so find $a$ such that $T(0) = - T(q)$. Then check that this really solves the problem.